# iframe post-form using fb:friendselector passing values

Tags: facebook, forms, post, iframe

I am trying to build an facebook-iframe application, where you can select friends to send them some information.

So i build a form method="post", put in some input fields, and a friend selector.
The fb:friend input field is renderd .. works fine.. but it doesn't pass over the selected friends.

Do i have to fix it by javascript?
Is there a simpler solution?

thx sven

Code:

```
<form action="http://xxx.net/index.php" method="post" target="_top">
    <input id="sometext" name="sometext" type="text" size="30" maxlength="30">
    <br/>
    <fb:serverFbml>
        <script type="text/fbml">
            <fb:fbml>
                <fb:friend-selector uid="$user" name="$user" idname="friendselector"/>
            </fb:fbml>
        </script>
    </fb:serverFbml><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, to my knowledge you *can't* fix it with Javascript.

I need more details (!), but it sounds like you may be attempting to use the FBML implementation of fb-friend-selector, without fb-request-form.

If so, try this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/request-form/

(!) Can you post your HTML code here?  It's likely an implementation issue that we can figure out through your code.

Comment: another important point would be, is it possible to user the multifriendselector... for something else than / or without.. inviting people to your application?

Comment: Unfortunately, you'd need to roll your own friend selector for that sort of custom behavior.  You could pull down the users' names/images/ids via the Graph API, then render them to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i am not alone, so here is an other way to cope with it.

Facebook-like styled Multifriendselector.

http://mike.brevoort.com/2010/08/10/introducing-the-jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector-plugin/